# how to install fonts without copy to font(windows) folder

Tags: c#, windows, macos, fonts, operating-system

I want to make a windows application where people can buy the fonts License of the yearly or monthly base so need to font installs without copy to font(windows) folder. how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows stores list of all fonts in registry: "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts". By default, fonts are referenced with file name only in these registry records and windows automatically searches them in fonts directory, but probably you can add fonts from other folders also by their full path.